# Mysql queries from bash file

Tags: bash, scripting, mysql

I'd like to run multiple MySQL queries and save them to specified files. Queries are saved in a bash script, `queries.sh`, e.g.:

```
cat queries.sh
mysql -u <user> -p <DBname> -e "select Col1 from Table1 where Condition;" > /home/<user>/queries/Col1Table1Cond
mysql -u <user> -p <DBname> -e "select Col5 from Table2 where Condition;" > /home/<user>/queries/Col5Table2Cond
```

Executing the script is not enough, since `<user>` has to input his password at each query and this is compromising the script flow.

Comment: So what do you plan to do ? Keep the password in a variable ? Parse commandline switch ??

Comment: How about storing the password as an environment variable or in another file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
user="jonnDoe"
dbname="customers"
password="VerySecret"

mysql -u $user -D $dbname -p $password -e "select Col1 from Table1 where Condition;" > /home/$user/queries/Col1Table1Cond
mysql -u $user -D $dbname -p $password -e "select Col5 from Table2 where Condition;" > /home/$user/queries/Col5Table2Cond
```

#### A better practice is to configure mysql `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file with the password inside, this way, no need to enter it each times :

```
[client]
password    = your_password
```

In this later case, remove all password related things from previous script

Answer (score 1):

There usually are a few different ways to achieve this.

#### Store it in an external file containing only the password:

```
$cat password.txt
Password

$cat queries.sh
mysql -u <user> -p$(cat password.txt) <rest of the command>
```

#### Store it in another shell script:

```
$cat settings.sh
PASSWORD=Password

$cat queries.sh
source settings.sh
mysql -u <user> -p"$PASSWORD" <rest of the command>
```

#### Store it in an environment variable called PASSWORD:

```
$cat queries.sh
mysql -u <user> -p"$PASSWORD" <rest of the command>
```

Also, see [How to auto login mysql in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814413/how-to-auto-login-mysql-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Thanks Barun. I think this solution is more portable if the script needs to be executed by different users with personal password.

Comment: Avoid using envoronment variables as stated by [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html). IF you use an external file, make sure only you have access to it `chmod 0600 password.txt`